# No module named 'kivy.graphics.instructions' while trying to use kivy master

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, python-for-android

My app works well while using kivy==2.0.0 and kivymd, but it doesn't display numeric keyboard in android devices.
So as I investigated,I've got to use master branch of kivy to solve this issue.Now when I run the app with master branch I receive this error :

" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.graphics.instructions' "

Even when I run kivy's examples I receive the same error.
Please tell me what should I do, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have same error but solved by just changing `kivy==2.0.0` to `kivy==2.1.0` in buildozer.spec requirements.